# Marketo REST API - Company API disabled error

Tags: marketo

I am having trouble getting company information using the Marketo REST Apis. (Describe Company » Marketo Developers )

Everytime I use the call

/rest/v1/companies/describe.json?access_token=

I always get the Error
[{\"code\":\"1018\",\"message\":\"Company API disabled\"}]}

However when I check on the User Role permissions I have enabled I seem to have access to all of the APIs.

[image]
Is there any other permissions I need to use the Company API?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The Company API is only available on instances where there is no native CRM sync, such as Microsoft Dynamics or Salesforce, enabled.  Your instance probably has one of these enabled and so the company API is not available.

Comment: Thanks for the response!! Is there any other way to get Company information, via an API call (where there is a native CRM sync). Our product allows customers to connect their Marketo account and we would like to have metadata such as the orgId and Account Name to present to the customer that we successfully connected to their account

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to obtain subscription info for a particular Marketo instance, and not to get metadata about Company records in Marketo.  There aren't any calls that return that in Marketo.

Answer (score 1):

sometimes the company information is wrapped up with the person/lead object. Maybe you can get it from a lead from a company?